# How to print the whole asp.net webpage on a single button click event using VB?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

How to print the whole asp.net webpage on a single button click event using VB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No Server side code required.you can use javascript inbuilt function print().

```
<input type=button name=print value="Print" onclick="javascript:window.print()">
```

**EDIT:**

If you are using server control button then create a javascript function and call this function on **OnClientClick** event.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    function PrintPage() {
        window.print();
    }
</script>



    <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" runat="server" Text="Print" OnClientClick="javascript:PrintPage();" />
```

Comment: i m using standard asp.net button

Answer (score 2):

Why use VB for this?  Printing is a client-side operation, just call `window.print()` in JavaScript.  Here are some [examples](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/beyond/javascript/article.php/3471121/Print-a-Web-Page-Using-JavaScript.htm).

Comment: @user594849: Technically, you're using a non-standard button :)  Is the button performing any server-side action as well, or does it only print?  If the latter, then this solution will work.  If the former, then when the page re-loads after the postback [shudder] then you can register a client-side startup script from the server-side code which includes `window.print();`.